# Android:Problems uploading an image to a Web Serbice with Apache Server

Tags: java, android, web-services, tomcat, upload

I´m new in Android and Web Services, especially in these ones, and I'm trying to create a web service with a web service in order to store the images sent from an Android app. However I have a problem uploading the image to the server and this doesn't show. Where is supposed to be stored? Another problem is that even I created a Web Service it only says HelloWorld, the one created at first in NetBeans.
Here is the logcat log:

```
04-01 00:03:55.831: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4384): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-01 00:03:55.831: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4384): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-01 00:04:55.792: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4384): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-01 00:04:55.792: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4384): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-01 00:05:45.074: I/System.out(4555): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
04-01 00:05:45.074: I/System.out(4555): buffer returned 
04-01 00:05:45.089: D/dalvikvm(4555): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 9% free 7518K/8195K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
04-01 00:05:45.097: I/dalvikvm-heap(4555): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.278MB for 4579316-byte allocation
04-01 00:05:45.113: D/dalvikvm(4555): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 6% free 11988K/12679K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 18ms
04-01 00:05:45.285: D/libEGL(4555): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-01 00:05:45.285: D/libEGL(4555): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-01 00:05:45.292: D/libEGL(4555): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-01 00:05:45.371: D/OpenGLRenderer(4555): Enabling debug mode 0
04-01 00:05:45.691: I/System.out(4555): Status is HTTP/1.1 200 OK
04-01 00:05:45.691: I/System.out(4555): Response: <!DOCTYPE html><html>    <head>        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">        <title>JSP Page</title>    </head>    <body>        <h1>Hello World!</h1>    </body></html>
```

This is the Web Service create with NetBeans and Apache Tomcat and the one which should retrieve the image. I dont know why but when I launch the server it only shows HelloWorld

```
@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of GenericResource
     */
    public GenericResource() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of za.org.droid.GenericResource
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @POST
@Path("/images")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response imageUpload(@FormDataParam("image") InputStream hereIsImage, @FormDataParam("image") FormDataContentDisposition hereIsName) {
    String path = System.getenv("HOME")+"/tmp/";
    if(hereIsName.getSize()==0) {
        return Response.status(500).entity("image parameter is missing").build();
    }
    String name = hereIsName.getFileName();
    path += name;

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = hereIsImage.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Response.status(500).entity(name + " was not uploaded\n"+e.getMessage()).build();
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(name + " was uploaded").build();
}
}
```

Finally here is the code of the Android Application which takes the image from the SDCard and send it to the Server.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Bitmap bm;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/DCIM/FinalM8.JPG");
        if(bm==null)
            throw new Exception("no picture!");
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = 
            new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.35:8080/WebApplication4");
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "FinalM8.JPG");
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("image", bab);
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        System.out.println("Status is "+response.getStatusLine());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
        System.out.println("Response: " + s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
}
```

I will appreciate some help becuase im quite new to WebServices and feel free to use the code if you think is useful for you

Thank you for your time

Comment: Please don't use `System.out` in Android apps. Use the intended `Log` class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see any `OutOfMemoryError` on the Android side, but this is not the way you should be uploading a file.

You are attempting to read the file from the SD card and uncompress it into a `Bitmap` and then recompress it into a .jpg byte array and upload that.

This causes obvious problems:

1. The `Bitmap` will be too large for many devices and cause an
   `OutOfMemoryError`.
2. The image you send will be different than the original, because of
   the decode and then the encode.
3. Instead of a hardcoded path to the SD card, consider using: 
   `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Instead of sending a `Bitmap`, you should open the file as an `InputStream` and send that.

**Example**:

```
String url = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/FinalM8.JPG";
File f_path = new File(url);
InputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f_path));
int d;
while ((d = fis.read()) != -1) {
    bos.write(d);
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thank your for the tips. However in this case this is not the problem (for the moment). The problem remains that in theory the device sends the image but there is no image nor file in the server.

Comment: The issue I addressed on the Android device may be secondary as long as you are sure that there is no `Exception` caught in the Android LogCat that could explain the failed upload completion from the client side. Is there any possibility of `Exception` that you may have missed on Android? It is unusual for any Android device to be able to open a full-size image on the SD card without a scale factor or an `OutOfMemmoryError`, especially if the image was taken by the camera.

Comment: Hi David, the part of code where the image is transformed into bitmap is taken from one tutorial which works in theory.As I said, I'm very new into web services, but I guess the problem is in the web service part because the response it gives to the Android device is the message "Hello World" (Part of code which is generated at first, but that I deleted in NetBeans)

Comment: Yea. That makes sense to me. If you verify that there is no `Exception` in Android, Do keep this answer as an optimization once you get the Web Services working because the advice is sound. Good luck Katherine!

Comment: Thanks again David, I posted the state in the logcat and in theory the device is getting connected to the webservice   00:05:45.691: I/System.out(4555): Status is HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: I see that you did get that 200 from the start.

Comment: I suggest that you modify your `imageUpload()` function on the server to log `name`, `path`, and total number of bytes (you will have to build this in your `while` loop. It isn't too difficult to find the log output for Apache.